# Display entries linked from Matrix field according to the entries' structure and a light switch in the Matrix

Tags: entries, matrix, relations, structure, lightswitch

In a channel (market), I have a Matrix field (market_products) with a Stucture-based Entries field (products) and a Lightswitch field (active/inactive). For each market, I need to create an ordered list of products, following the Structure hierarchy of the original products channel, and including a link according to the active/inactive light switch.

I can create a list of products styled according the the lightswitch, but ordered by the order in the Matrix field:

```
{% set allProducts in entry.market_products %}

{% for each in allProducts.theProduct %}
    {% set theSwitch = allProducts.active %}

    {% if theSwitch == "1" %}
        <li><a href="/search/{{each.slug}}">{{ each.title }}</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li>{{ each.title }}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or a list of related products ordered by the product structure, but not styled according to the lightswitch:

```
{% set allProducts = craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo({
    sourceElement: entry.id,
    field: 'market_products.theProduct'
}) %}

{% nav productList in allProducts %}
    <li>
        <a href="/search/{{ productList.slug }}" title="{{ productList.title }}">{{ productList.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
            {% children %}
        </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
{% endnav %}
```

But how do I create an array of products, ordered by the products' structure AND filtered according to the lightswitch?